# angularjs $http is throwing error 500 (Internal Server Error) when groupby in linq is used and passed as json

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

angularjs $http is throwing error 500 (Internal Server Error) when groupby in linq is used and passed as json

I have 2 classes Offer and OfferDetails

```
public class OfferDetails
{
    public long? eventid { get; set; }
    public List<Offer> offer { get; set; }
}


public class Offer
{
    public long OfferId { get; set; }
    public string OfferType { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> EventId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> OfferDiscount { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> NoofPeople { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> UserId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedIp { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedIp { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

When I am calling the method offerdetailsjson() using angularjs $http and putting breakpoint on method offerdetailsjson() then it is running fine but $http throws error

```
 public JsonResult offerdetailsjson()
    {
        List<OfferDetails> r = repository.Offers.GetAll().GroupBy(x => x.EventId).Select(x => new OfferDetails
        {
            eventid = x.Key,
            offer = x.ToList()
        }).ToList();
        return Json(r);
}


<script>
    angular.module('app', []).controller("OfferListCtrl", OfferListController);
    OfferListController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];
    function OfferListController($scope, $http) {

        $http({
            url: '/Master/offerdetails',
            method: 'post',

        }).then(function (response) {
            debugger
            alert(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        }, function () { alert('Failed'); });

    }
</script>
```

I will be thankful if someone can help me.

Comment: The internal server error is thrown by the server and not by AngularJS

Comment: But I am putting breakpoint and getting no exception only $http is throwing error where I have put an alert Failed

Comment: Check the logs of your server and you will see the line where the error occurs